# qualtrics contacts api extRef

Tags: api, contacts, qualtrics

I am using the Qualtrics API to create contacts in a mailing list. In making a call to https://ca1.qualtrics.com/API/v3/mailinglists/ML_identity/contacts I am pushing a json string containing extRef. However, I keep getting the following response:

```
 "httpStatus": "400 - Bad Request",
    "error": {
        "errorMessage": "Unexpected json key provided: extRef",
        "errorCode": "RP_9"
    },
```

The documentation clearly states extRef is what the field is called. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The field should be externalDataRef instead of extRef (Qualtrics is inconsitent when it comes to that field). See: [https://api.qualtrics.com/api-reference/reference/researchCore.json/paths/~1mailinglists~1{mailingListId}~1contacts/post](https://api.qualtrics.com/api-reference/reference/researchCore.json/paths/%7E1mailinglists%7E1%7BmailingListId%7D%7E1contacts/post)

Note that the API call is specific to Research Core Contacts. XM Directory uses a different API call to add a contact.

Comment: I tried so many version of that field name I found in so many different places. Turns out externalDataRef is the one. Thank you.